# What is the maximum recommended size for an .OBJ file used with .JSON loader?

Tags: three.js

I've downloaded a few blender models and I've noticed some of them are huge after turning into .obj files.   Some are so big they never load.  I would think the models should be less than 20 MB, but it's seems tough to live up to considering the size and detail of so many 3D files.

Comment: well, as a general rule, obj-files are the biggest file format concerning file size. So if you already have a json-model , just stick with it? Also, there is a binary loader if you need very low file sizes.